# How to integrate AWS Cognito Identity Pool and API Gateway in the Javascript sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to protect access to API Gateway using Cognito Identiy Pool (to which for now I authorize using Cognito User Pools, but later I may user other providers like facebook etc.)

So from the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html)

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
  Logins: {
    'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>': 'some-user-pool-token'
  }
});
AWS.config.credentials.refresh((error) => {
    ...
}
```

But to use API Gateway (from an generated sdk) I need:

```
accessKey: 'ACCESS_KEY',
secretKey: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

My questions:

1. How do I get the ACCES_KEY and SECRET_KEY?
2. The only reason I need a dependency to the aws sdk is, that I need to call `credentials.refresh`. Can I somehow do this withpout the aws sdk (and only the amazon-cognito-identity-js as well as the generated api gateway sdk)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for 1 can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html).

And it is done like this:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
  Logins: {
    'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>': 'some-user-pool-token'
  }
});
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){

    // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
    var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
    var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
    var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;

});
```

So I guess the answer to 2 is: Yes, one also needs the AWS SDK for getting the credentials.